# converting roman numerals to integer- unclear about variables in leetcode question 13 solution

Tags: python, python-3.x, roman-numerals

I know `s` is the string of roman numerals but because I don't know what `i`  stand for, I am not sure what `s[i]` means. I am trying to understand the solution that is posted line by line, but am stuck with this specific part. All help is appreciated, I understand the roman numeral system fully.

[problem attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8qMz.png)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with the code as text in the body of the question, rather than as an image or link

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

"i" is the index of the character being examined in "s". Index starts at 0.
"total" is an accumulator. It is the sum of values of each roman character.